# Different transition to body and content

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I had a look around but couldn't find a solution for this.

How can I override the `#wait`, `#about` and `a` transitions with the `body` one? I want the font size to resize faster.

Thanks.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10vw
}
body {
  -webkit-transition: font .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: font .2s ease;
  -o-transition: font .2s ease;
  transition: font .2s ease;
}
#wait,
#about,
a {
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
  -o-transition: all .6s ease;
  transition: all .6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="wait">
  <div id="about">
    1 2 3 4 <a href="#">5</a> 6 7 8 9 0
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the rules have same timing .2s if you want a faster than body add .1s

Comment: @GermanoPlebani sorry, updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the !important.

```
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease !important;
```

If you place that on the body, then it will override the other style.

Answer (score 0):

```
#wait,
#about,
a {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease !important;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease !important;
  transition: all .2s ease !important;
}
```

Whenever you want to override a css and style doesn't apply use !important at end of style code

Answer (score 0):

You can specify 2 or more comma-separated transitions, using a single transition property:

```css
#wait {
  font-size: 5vw;
  transition: all 2s ease, font .2s ease;
}

#wait:hover {
  font-size: 10vw;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="wait">
  TEEEST
</p>
```